# Nested Case: how can i write correctly?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Select case
  When book_id is not null 
    then case when title = title_id then title_id end
  Else '0' end 
from table
```

Logic is  case in case! How can I write properly? 
Generally can I write like this?

Comment: First things first: Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: @mathguy oracle, but it doesnt matter for me can i write this case in case

Comment: In Oracle, that is a valid statement (nested CASE expressions). You can write it like that. It is not clear what it does (you didn't describe your base table, and what "title" is in the when condition, etc.) but in principle it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE    WHEN book_id is not null
    THEN CASE 
                    WHEN title=title_id
                    THEN title_id
                    ELSE 0 
         END,
    ELSE CASE 
                    WHEN "Handle the other cases for book"
                    THEN "Case 2"
                    ELSE "Default for other Case" 
         END
END
```

Comment: Suggestion: when you look at a question, inspect the tags. If you see `MySQL` and `Oracle` both, that should be the first question to the OP. A MySQL solution is unlikely to solve an Oracle question, and vice versa, so there isn't much gain from answering before asking for clarification on the tag.